# Inheritance in DynamoDB Mapper

Tags: inheritance, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a class

```
ItemMdl{

  String id;
  @DynamoDBAttribute
  @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
  public String getId() {
     return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

and inherited it in the Table class

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "organization")
   public class OrganizationMdl extends ItemMdl{
   ...
}
```

When I am uploading the data, no property of the parent class is getting populated in the dynamodb. I have found some resources like [Support for inheritance in DynamoDbMapper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/832), and found it is not yet supported. Is there a way to achieve it?